# Oracle data export using Liquibase causing OOM

Tags: spring-boot, maven, liquibase

I am getting an exception while exporting the data from Oracle database using Liquibase.

I have used below maven command

```
**mvn -e -X liquibase:generateChangeLog -Dliquibase.diffTypes=data -DargLine= "-Xms10G -Xmx 20G -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit"**
```

last line I can see in the log before failing is,

```
[DEBUG] Executing with the 'jdbc' executor
```

When I checked the same in Java Visual VM, I found that `**liquibase.change.ColumnConfig**` class is consuming 80% of space, this is more likely a memory leakage issue.

On top of this when I checked the java memory space, I can see Old Gen space is utilized 100% and it never goes down after 50 mins of execution.

I would like to know is there a way to export a data for few specific tables, if so please help with the maven command. I tried out below, but it didn't work out for me.

```
**mvn -e -X liquibase:generateChangeLog -Dliquibase.diffTypes=data,table -Dliquibase.includeObjects="table:myTable" -DargLine= "-Xms10G -Xmx 20G -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit"**
```

The version of Liquibase I am using is 4.2.0

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What error do you see when you tried out the second command? `includeObjects` property should have worked.

Comment: No, result was same OOM.. although there was only 10 records in table.
It seems that command doesn't works with combination of data.

Comment: The cmd has `-XmX 20G` - but the option is `-Xmx`. Options are case sensitive.

Comment: yes, it was typo here. originally it was -Xmx while running command.